# Text near textinput in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to write a text and a textinput to the left of the screen, but text goes to the left, while textinput goes to the right. I want them close. I made several tests by inserting float or boxlayouts but during resizing the textinput is moved. I would like something like this:

```
age []
```

But i have something like this (without dots):

```
Age...........................................[]
```

This is my code:

```
        BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 1,1
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: .3,1
            Label:
                text: "Age"
                font_size: dp(20)
                text_size: self.size
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .8,1 
                halign: "left"
                valign: "middle"
            TextInput:
                id: age
                size_hint: None,.6
                font_size: dp(20)
                width: self.font_size*3
                input_filter: "int"
                multiline: False
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "center_y":0.5}
```